# Material Table - is it possible to move row selection text from toolbar to the bottom of page

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, material-table

I'm using Material Table at the moment and am having difficulty customizing the position of the selection text (presented when one or more rows are selected via the checkbox).

Looking at the documents, I can see that the toolbar is overridable (https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding), however the examples show simpler changes e.g. how to change the background color. I wonder if it's possible to separate the  selection text from the toolbar and render it in a different location, like the below picture demonstrates.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I turned off the row selection text in the toolbar by using `showTextRowsSelected: false`

I then made a custom footer using the row data presented by the onSelectionChange handler.